# Elixir remove nil from list

Tags: list, elixir

I got the following structure:

```
[nil,
 %{attributes: %{updated_at: ~N[2017-09-21 08:34:11.899360]},
 ...]
```

I want to remove the nils. How do I do that? Tried `Enum.reduce/3` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 77):

[`Enum.filter/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#filter/2) comes to the rescue:

```
Enum.filter(list, & !is_nil(&1))
```

---

If you are certain there could not be `false` atoms in the list (the other possible falsey value in Elixir,) the filter might be simplified to:

```
Enum.filter(list, & &1)
```

---

Also (credits to @Dogbert) there is a counterpart function [`Enum.reject/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reject/2) that “returns elements of `enumerable` for which the function `fun` returns `false` or `nil`.”

```
Enum.reject(list, &is_nil/1)
```

Comment: Ahhh, nice. Tried something like List.delete. Filter, thanks. Solution was 
    data = Enum.filter(data, & !is_nil(&1))

Comment: False is not included, so I need only to check for nil. Your solution works perfect. Thanks again :) I make a query before for the last changes in the databse. With a new databse I got some nils and had to remove them.

Comment: Also: `Enum.reject(list, &is_nil/1)`.

Comment: `Enum.reject(list, &is_nil/1)` is particularly elegant—nice solution

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me :

```
Enum.filter(s, fn x -> if(x != "") do x end end)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Enum.filter(list, fn x -> x != "" end)
```

Comment: Hi! Please [edit] your answer to expand a little bit upon how the code snippet you posted works. Thanks!